# Learning Haskell, understanding data structures

Tags: haskell

I m actually learning Haskell and I'm trying to make a simple FizzBuzz Kata.

The idea is to take a list of numbers as entry, and to produce a list of Numbers | String following these rules:

- fizzBuzz:: [StringInt] -> [StringInt]
- every multiple of 3, the item in the list should be "Fizz"
- every multiple of 5, the item in the list should be "Buzz"
- otherwise it should be the number

Here the code I've produced:

```
module FizzBuzz where 

data StringInt a = Int a | String a

handleRule:: StringInt a -> a
handleRule x
    | x % 3 == 0 = StringInt "Fizz"
    | x % 5 == 0 = StringInt "Buzz"
    | otherwise = x

run:: [StringInt a] -> [a]
run = map handleRule
```

While trying to run the following tests:

```
module FizzBuzzSpec (spec) where

    import Test.Hspec
    import FizzBuzz

    spec :: Spec
    spec = describe "FizzBuzz#run" $ do
        it "should have displayed Fizz for number 3" $
            run [1..10]:2 `shouldBe` "Fizz"
        it "should have displayed Buzz for number 5" $
            run [1..10]:4 `shouldBe` "Buzz"
```

I'm having the following outputs:

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ StringInt a
• In the expression: x
  In an equation for ‘handleRule’:
      handleRule x
        | (%) x 3 == 0 = StringInt "Fizz"
        | (%) x 5 == 0 = StringInt "Buzz"
        | otherwise = x
• Relevant bindings include
    x :: StringInt a (bound at src/FizzBuzz.hs:6:12)
    handleRule :: StringInt a -> a (bound at src/FizzBuzz.hs:6:1)
```

|
9 |         | otherwise = x

*Important Note: I'm really a new Haskell player, sorry if I'm making horrible things right there.*

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

---

EDIT:

I've tried by using:

```
module FizzBuzz where 

type StringInt = Either Int String

handleRule:: Int -> StringInt
handleRule x
    | x `mod` 3 == 0 = Right "Fizz"
    | x `mod` 5 == 0 = Right "Buzz"
    | otherwise      = Left x

run:: [Int] -> [StringInt]
run = map handleRule
```

And

```
module FizzBuzzSpec (spec) where

    import Test.Hspec
    import FizzBuzz

    spec::Spec
    spec = describe "FizzBuzz#run" $ do
        it "should have displayed Fizz for number 3" $
            run [1..10]:2 `shouldBe` Right "Fizz"
        it "should have displayed Buzz for number 5" $
            run [1..10]:4 `shouldBe` Right "Buzz"
```

But that always throws

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[StringInt]]’
                  with actual type ‘Either a0 [Char]’
    • In the second argument of ‘shouldBe’, namely ‘Right "Fizz"’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘run [1 .. 10] : 2 `shouldBe` Right "Fizz"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        it "should have displayed Fizz for number 3"
          $ run [1 .. 10] : 2 `shouldBe` Right "Fizz"
  |
9 |                         run [1..10]:2 `shouldBe` Right "Fizz"
  |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/pc/Soft/haskell/hello-stack/test/FizzBuzzSpec.hs:11:50: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[StringInt]]’
                  with actual type ‘Either a1 [Char]’
    • In the second argument of ‘shouldBe’, namely ‘Right "Buzz"’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘run [1 .. 10] : 4 `shouldBe` Right "Buzz"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        it "should have displayed Buzz for number 5"
          $ run [1 .. 10] : 4 `shouldBe` Right "Buzz"
   |
11 |                         run [1..10]:4 `shouldBe` Right "Buzz"
   |                              

                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can't get the point out of here...

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: If you want to access an element of a list, don't use a :, use a !!
For example:  ([1..10] !! 2) == 3

Comment: Don't forget that some numbers are multiples of both 3 and 5. In some variants of FizzBuzz, handling that case is the main point of the exercise.

Comment: Yeah, thank you :). Seems that guard is a good approach to resolve this. WYT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that by the following line:

```
data StringInt a = Int a | String a
```

you're going to define a sum type. But actually, it requires data constructor provided:

```
data StringInt = Left Int | Right String
```

Or, there's already `Either` type, which helps to define a sum type, so you can just create a type alias. Thus, your program is going to look like this

```
type StringInt = Either Int String

handleRule:: Int -> StringInt
handleRule x
    | mod x 3 == 0 = Right "Fizz"
    | mod x 5 == 0 = Right "Buzz"
    | otherwise = Left x

run:: [Int] -> [StringInt]
run = map handleRule
```

And the test should also be modified, since the return value is not just a string, but a string wrapped in `Right`:

```
module FizzBuzzSpec (spec) where

import Test.Hspec
import FizzBuzz

spec::Spec
spec = describe "FizzBuzz#run" $ do
    it "should have displayed Fizz for number 3" $
        run [1..10] !! 2 `shouldBe` (Right "Fizz")
    it "should have displayed Buzz for number 5" $
        run [1..10] !! 4 `shouldBe` (Right "Buzz")

main :: IO()
main = hspec spec
```

To run the tests:

```
runhaskell Tests.hs
```

By the way, you can skip the sum types for now, just by returning a string representation of a number if it can't be divided by `3` or `5`:

```
handleRule:: Int -> String
handleRule x
    | mod x 3 == 0 = "Fizz"
    | mod x 5 == 0 = "Buzz"
    | otherwise = show x

run:: [Int] -> [String]
run = map handleRule
```

Comment: The idea is to use types and to try to understand them, I would prefer the first proposition and try to make it work :) . Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually the parenthesis in `(Right "Fuzz")` were crucial. And if you want to get nth element from list `!!` function should be used, not `:`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

The rule should be something like this:

```
data StringInt = SI_Str String
               | SI_Int Int

handleRule:: Int -> StringInt
handleRule x
    | x `mod` 3 == 0 = SI_Str "Fizz"
    | x `mod` 5 == 0 = SI_Str "Buzz"
    | otherwise      = SI_Int x
```

When you describe a "data", you're actually describing a data type. The left sife of the equation is the name of the type and in this case the name of the type is StringInt. On the right side of the equation you describe the constructor (or constructor, as is in this case) how you can create the data type. In this case, we have 2 constructors the can create "datas" of type StringInt - the SI_Str constructor and the SI_Int constructor. How you distinguish between them and access their "data contents" is called pattern-matching.  Trying not to spoil the fun of learning though, I suggest starting carrying on from there.